# Excel / Power Bi – Group fixed numbers in dozens like price filters in eshops

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-powerbi

I have a table of data in Microsoft Power Bi:

```
IS-1   32
IS-2   76
IS-3   27
IS-4   35
IS-5   14
IS-6   81
```

And I need to create a new column with a function which will group those numbers in decaded so they can be easily represented in charts.

```
IS-1   32    31-40
IS-2   76    71-80
IS-3   27    21-30
IS-4   35    31-40
IS-5   14    11-20
IS-6   81    81-90
```

I know that it will be almost the same for Microsoft Excel so you can provide an Excel function.

Comment: Can you please someone explain me why this question removed my privilege to create questions? So I will not make this mistake again in other networks?

Comment: You say "dozens", but you show groups of 10 (which might be called "decades").

Comment: Oh! I got confused... My bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

```
Group Size = IF(ISNUMBER(Data[Size]);CEILING(Data[Size]; 10)-9&" - "&CEILING(Data[Size];10))
```

(Microsoft Power Bi Formula)